# Formik Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldProps' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

I am using Formik to create form. When I use `FieldArray` in one of the form I get error saying `Field.tsx:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldProps' of undefined`

To verify if I am doing something wrong, I copied example from documents and used it. Unfortunately, example from the docs didn't work. Any idea why it could go worong?

Here is the example I copied to my project and it didn't work: https://formik.org/docs/examples/field-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, figured it out. I was getting the error because `webpack/typescript` in watch mode was not transpiling the changes properly. Restarting the webpack dev server fixed the problem.

Comment: exactly what should we do

Comment: This is late, but might be helpful to someone else but restarting your app is what he meant. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally did not wrap my views inside of Formik element which caused this same error. My solution was to wrap the views properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your component is ultimately inside a Formik element.

```
<Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    {({ isSubmitting, status, setFieldValue }) => (

         <... your component should be somewhere here ...>
    )}
</Formik>
```